# WordPress multisite storing xml feed

Tags: wordpress

I developed a WordPress plugin. It retrieves a xml feed with data and stores a cached version in the plugin folder. So far so good. The problem is with multisite. In multisite the plugin can only make use of that 1 cached file. If users of multisite subsites want to use a different xml file that's not possible. How do you create different local storage in the plugin for each multisite subsite?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it myself. I used get_current_blog_id() in de filesname of the feed. In that way I can store files separately.